# Excel - apply formula while pasting columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, copy-paste

I am copying a column from one excel file, where values are in milliseconds to another excel file where I need the value in seconds. Usually I copy and paste the column in a temporary column (lets call it TEMP) of the destination excel sheet, apply formula (=TEMPx/1000) across the destination column, and then copy the destination column over itself (by value) and delete the temp column.

I was wondering I could save some steps in the process?

Note that I do not want to keep any references, since the file I am copying from is temporary. Also I don't want to keep the temporary column since I will copying 100s of such columns from different files.

Answer (score 1):

Just apply your formula to the destination column directly, then copy and paste values directly over itself.

```
=sheet1!A1/1000
```

Comment: Might want to add a little more information here about how to create cross-sheet (or cross-workbook) cell references. Perhaps explain how you can type `=` then using the mouse navigate to and click on the source data, and the formula in the destination cell will automatically create that cell reference for you. As is, given the likely expertise level demonstrated by the question, this answer may not quite be actionable for this asker.

Answer (score 0):

As Brian alluded to, there is no need to use a temporary column. Excel formulas allow you take an input value, do some calculation, and return an output value in a single cell. So if you put the calculation to convert the time (in my screenshot, the column B value) directly into your destination column (my column C), your converted value ends up in the destination column.

The first screenshot shows the "output" values of each cell. The second screenshot shows the cells from a formula perspective. You can use <kbd>Ctrl Key</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> (tilde) to switch between cell viewing modes.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think if you re-read the question carefully you'll find that you've explained the asker's method to the asker using screenshots. Your column `B` IS the temp column, as you've copied it out of the source file and pasted it into column `B`.